# Lejos NXT - How can i detect a motor stall?

Tags: lejos-nxj

I try to build a Rubiks Cube Solver with 4 arms to grab the cube.
I am using the lejos firmware version 0.9.0. My problem is how can i detect that a motor is stalled?

For example:
Motor.A rotates forward while the motor will be blocked/stalled,
then Motor.A should stop.

I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you're looking for:

**isStalled()**

`NXTRegulatedMotor.isStalled()` - Return true if the motor is currently stalled. (i.e. move count shows less rotation degrees than expected)
http://www.lejos.org/nxt/nxj/api/lejos/nxt/NXTRegulatedMotor.html#isStalled()

Another method you should be aware of is this:

**setStalledThreshold()**

`NXTRegulatedMotor.setStallThreshold()` - Set the parameters for detecting a stalled motor. A motor will be recognised as stalled if the movement error (the amount the motor lags the regulated position) is greater than error for a period longer than time.
[http://www.lejos.org/nxt/nxj/api/lejos/nxt/NXTRegulatedMotor.html#setStallThreshold(int, int)](http://www.lejos.org/nxt/nxj/api/lejos/nxt/NXTRegulatedMotor.html#setStallThreshold)

And finally here's an example of how to put it all together:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    boolean stalled = false;
    NXTRegulatedMotor motor_arm = Motor.A;
    motor_arm.setStallThreshold(1, 100);

    motor_arm.setSpeed(400);
    motor_arm.backward();

    while (! stalled)
    {
        LCD.drawString("Motor is rotating", 0, 0);
        if(motor_arm.isStalled())
        {
           motor_arm.stop();
           stalled=true;
           LCD.drawString("Motor is stalled", 0, 0);
           Delay.msDelay(3000);
        }

        Delay.msDelay(100);
    }

}
```

**Notice:** The values for `setStalledThreshold()` are likely to be **mechanically-dependent**, if you use gears to connect the motor to the stalling mechanism the values for correct stall detection may vary according to the design of your robot.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think checking whether the position changes is the only way. Send the move command, wait, check the position, see if it's what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks,
but the API has functions called isStalled() and setStallThreshold. Anybody know, how does it works? Ive tried some implementations but no of them works. How must or can i use these functions?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the motor.getPosition() should be the same as motor.getTachoCount(). If it is not, then you can assume that the motor is stalled.

> public float getPosition()
>
> Returns the current position that the motor
>   regulator is trying to maintain. Normally this will be the actual
>   position of the motor and will be the same as the value returned by
>   getTachoCount(). However in some circumstances (activeMotors that are
>   in the process of stalling, or activeMotors that have been forced out
>   of position), the two values may differ. Note that if regulation has
>   been suspended calling this method will restart it.

So you just need to check whether the two values equal or not:

```
public boolean isStealed() {
    motor.getPosition() == motor.getTachoCount();
}
```